# Laravel 4 How to use Authority package

Tags: laravel, acl, rbac, authority

I have created model User and table users to store user information

I also have executed the migration script.

I have no idea how to log user in and make authority recognize the user.

I really need tutorial or sample application or anything that could help.

Thanks for reading.

Your help are much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are a couple of steps to many to describe here, but just have a look at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/authentication-with-laravel-4/.